# How to Find a Substring in a Particular String in a Set

Tags: c++, set, multimap

How do you find the substring within a string in a set? For example, if I enter "Ville," then Louisville, Gainesville, and Muellerville are found? I have tried the following code

```
for(string const& search : cities)
{
if(find(search.begin(), search.end(), str) != std::string::npos)
{
string y = search;
employees.emplace_back(y);
```

,but I cannot figure out what is wrong with my syntax. This code is used in the following project ([Project Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922474/returning-employee-and-salary-when-given-a-location-substring))

EDIT: My problem was simple and was fixed with using .begin() and .end() to iterate over the multimap name_address and finding each name with .substr. I also used a multimap instead of a set. I found the syntax easier and got it to work.

```
    for(auto it = name_address.begin(); it != name_address.end(); ++it)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < it->first.length(); ++i)
        {   
            string tmpstr3 = it->first.substr(0 + i, str.length());
            if(str == tmpstr3)
            {
               employees.insert(it->second);
               break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how to use `std::search`? Because this is not what `std::find` is for.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No, I am unfamiliar with std::search.

Comment: Well, I guess it's time to become familiar with it, because that's how this should be done.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Maybe, I am reading the documentation wrong, but it says std::search returns the first element found with the string in it. I need all elements.

Comment: Well, if it returns the iterator to the first element, and you know that you were searching for five characters, and you know that it returns the iterator to the first one, how difficult do you think it is to find where the remaining four are?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean that all you need is an iterator to "the first element". After all, a string literal in C++, like `"hello world"` is just a pointer to its first character. Somehow, C++ is always able to find the rest of the literal string. So, once you get the iterator to the first element, that `std::search` returns, you automatically know where the remaining elements are, by definition. That's how C++ iterators work. Isn't C++ awesome?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Okay, the element I am referring to is the element of the set and not each individual character of each string within the set. So would std::search work, for example, if I enter "Ville," then Louisville, Gainesville, and Muellerville are found or would it just get Louisville and not the others?

Comment: If you `std::search` the string "Louisville" for "Ville", you can use the `std::search` overload that takes an extra comparator closure, and supply one that does a case-insensitive comparison, so that a `std::search` of "Louisville" for "Ville" will return an iterator to 'v'. Like I said: isn't C++ awesome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely looking for

```
if (search.find(str) != std::string::npos)
```

The `std::find` call you have shouldn't compile.